# Python and env vars not working

Tags: python

I want to add an environment variable to my server, it needs to be a Boolean. I have added to `/etc/environment`:

```
PROD=True
```

I have logged the user in and out, now I am running this simple script to check if it works or not:

```
import os
if os.environ['PROD'] == True:
        print "prod"
```

however I a not getting a print out, what am I doing wrong here? Am I representing the bool incorrectly?

Comment: try `if os.environ['PROD'] == "True"` your environment probably doesnt have the concept of bool, it stores True as a string. you can always print the `type`

Answer (score 4):

Environment variables are `str` types.

Support Python 2.x and 3.x versions:

```
import os
if os.getenv('PROD') == 'True':
    print("prod")
```

protect you from `KeyError`.

In the documentation([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)):

> A mapping object representing the string environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the PROD environment variable is present in the os.environ(which is a dict inturn)

```
>>> if 'PROD' in os.environ:
...     print 'prod'
...
prod
```

Answer (score -1):

All environment variables are inherently strings. Try

```
import os
if os.environ['PROD'] == 'True':
    print "prod"
```

If you really need "typed environment variables" and are not afraid of using `eval` on potentially arbitrary strings, you may do something like

```
import os
PROD = eval(os.environ['PROD'])
if PROD == True:  # Or just "if PROD:"
    print "prod"
```

Comment: To anyone reading this: do __NOT__ use `eval()` on environment variable, __NEVER__ (well, unless you really want to let anyone break your system of course).